# SSIS Export Data from one to another table

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to understand why I am unable to export data from one table to another in SQL Server database.   Error message:

```
Copying to [dbo].[tbl_Diagnosis_Table] (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with input column "Code" (73) on input "Destination Input" (50). The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input" (50)" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (50)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - tbl_Diagnosis_Table" (37) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (50). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: I'm guessing there was an error with the input column "Code" such that the value violated the integrity constraints for the column

Comment: Do you understand what the violation of the integrity constraints means?

Comment: I do. So I need to change to value in another table linked thru foreign key?

Comment: Yes. You will need to make sure that the FK reference does not get violated. The table that you are trying to load has a column "Code" which is carrying a value not found in the other table. Hence the error.